# Running a Task method that has no await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Suppose I have the following method:

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomeStuffWithAsync()
{
   //do some stuff without calling await
   return true;
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
await DoSomeStuffWithAsync();
```

Does this run any differently to this method:

```
public bool DoSomeStuff()
{
   return true;
}
```

being called like this:

```
DoSomeStuff();
```

I am thinking that because `DoSomeStuffWithAsync` doesn't actually call `await` in its code that it will still run the same as `DoSomeStuff`.

Is there any benefit structuring my method like  `DoSomeStuffWithAsync`?

Comment: Are you asking if you should add the `async` keyword to methods that you know will always be synchronous? If so, the answer is no. If you're asking whether `await AsyncWithoutAnyAwaits()` is effectively synchronous, the answer is yes (as substantiated by the accompanying compiler error: `Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that using `async` for a method that does not use `await` is considered a bad style. If you have a synchronous method that returns a task, you should use `Task.FromResult` instead:

```
public Task<bool> DoSomeStuffWithAsync()
{
   return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

But yeah, that’s all this is: A synchronous method that returns a task. There is nothign asynchronous about it, so this does not actually run any differently than normal synchronous code that just returns a bool.

Is there still a benefit to returning a task instead of the value directly? That depends. Sometimes, you may have an asynchronous interface you need to implement but you don’t actually have an asynchronous implementation for it. But if you don’t have to do this and if you also don’t consider changing your implementation eventually to actually do something asynchronously, then there’s no benefit in making your method return a task.

As for the call, `await DoSomeStuffWithAsync()` will run `DoSomeStuffWithAsync()` and then await the task it returns. Since `DoSomeStuffWithAsync()` is synchronous, the task will return directly, and since the task is already completed, `await` will be able to directly continue. So this will be very similar to calling the method synchronously. The presence of that `await` does have an impact on the runtime behavior though, since this will make that calling method actually asynchronous (even if the called code is synchronous).

But it’s up to you to decide whether that’s appropriate in your case. In general though, you should probably avoid making this appear asynchronous when there isn’t a real asynchronous process involved.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. I found an async method that wasn't being awaited during some code analysis and was wondering if the async keyword actually made much of a difference before I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

In short terms `async` keyword does not make a method to run asynchronously. It only allows the method to call `await` keyword inside. That's where the magic happens. In your case you don't have any `await` keyword anywhere which indicates your method does not indeed run asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Your methods return different things.
DoSomeStuffWithAsync() returns a `Task<bool>`. You can call it without the 'async" keyword - synchronously - the compiler will return bool *wrapped in an instance of `Task<bool>`* once the method is complete - it does that behind the scenes. And another "difference" is how you handle the returned value...

```
var task = DoSomeStuffWithAsync(); // Synchronous call
Console.WriteLine(task.Result); // You must unpack the bool result...
```

Your other method just returns a bool - it's just a standard synchronous call/return...

```
var result = DoSomeStuff(); // Synchronous call
Console.WriteLine(result);  // Just use the result
```

From a behavior point-of-view, to answer your specific question, both behave synchronously. Another way to look at it:

```
var act = new Func<Task<bool>>(async () => await DoSomeStuffWithAsync()); 
var result = act(); // will complete when DoSomeStuffWithAsync completes
```

Hope this answers your question.